# Google-Ads Python Library - Module Not found

Tags: pip, google-ads-api

Someone please show me what I'm missing here. I've run the following command: `pip install google-ads` (see here: https://pypi.org/project/google-ads/) several times. I've also downloaded the tar and run the setup.py file (`python setup.py build install`).

Following the instructions, I try to import:

```
import google.ads.google_ads.client
```

and I get the following error consistently:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-df47157331b2> in <module>()
----> 1 import google.ads.google_ads.client

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.ads'
```

I can make a call using curl so I know that the configuration is set up properly. For what it's worth, I downloaded the Facebook marketing Python sdk an hour earlier and that works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This may occur if there is a mismatch between the versions of `pip` and `python` that you are using. As of V4.0 of this library, only Python 3.6+ is supported. Please try this again with pip3 and python3.